# View selector with an overlay drawable

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create a Button which would show up as :
- when pressed, it should show a darker shade of green with an overlay "check" mark
- otherwise, it should show up as a lighter shade of green.

Here is the drawable object that I am trying to use as background of my Button object:

```
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_check_black_24dp">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <size android:width="16dp" android:height="16dp" />
        <corners android:radius="8dp" />
        <gradient
            android:type="radial"
            android:gradientRadius="60dp"
            android:startColor="#64DD17"
            android:endColor="@android:color/black" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_pressed="false">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <size android:width="16dp" android:height="16dp" />
        <corners android:radius="8dp" />
        <gradient
            android:type="radial"
            android:gradientRadius="60dp"
            android:startColor="#76FF03"
            android:endColor="@android:color/black" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

The problem is that when pressed the button shows up only the "check" mark and not the green shape behind it. When not checked, the button shows the correct green shape.

I need help to understand how I can have the green shape and the "check" mark displayed when this button is pressed ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <size android:width="16dp" android:height="16dp" />
            <corners android:radius="8dp" />
            <gradient android:endColor="@android:color/black" android:gradientRadius="60dp" android:startColor="#64DD17" android:type="radial" />
        </shape>
    </item>


    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <size android:width="16dp" android:height="16dp" />
            <corners android:radius="8dp" />
            <gradient android:endColor="@android:color/black" android:gradientRadius="60dp" android:startColor="#76FF03" android:type="radial" />
        </shape>

    </item>
</selector>
```